# Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a simple text file that contains CSVs in the form of:

`First Name, Last Name, Gender, Age, Email, Occupation`.

I am reading this file into C# and then trying to split the properties by the comma and then append each piece of information to a `Person` class. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Text file location
            string fileLocation = @"C:\Users\naugh\Desktop\Example.txt";

            // Opens file, removes quotes and rewrites file
            string allText = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);
            string allTextNoQuotes = allText.Replace("\"", "");
            File.WriteAllText(fileLocation, allTextNoQuotes);

            // Creates a list entry for each line in file
            List<string> peopleList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation).ToList();
            
            // Blank Person list
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            foreach (string person in peopleList)
            {
                string[] entries = person.Split(",");

                Console.WriteLine(entries[1]);

                /*person1.FirstName = entries[0];
                person1.LastName = entries[1];
                person1.Gender = entries[2];
                person1.Age = entries[3];
                person1.Email = entries[4];
                person1.Occupation = entries[5];

                people.Add(person1);*/
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

As a test, I am printing `entries[1]` which prints all of the `Last Names` to my terminal. However, after it prints the last name I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
> outside the bounds of the array.

When I try and implement the code to add the information to the `Person` class (that is commented out), it returns the same error.

Is anyone able to shed some light please?

Comment: "after it prints the last name" - you're saying that it *does* print the last name (from `Console.WriteLine(entries[1])`) and the exception is thrown after that? Whichever line comes after that one doesn't have 5 commas.

Comment: Try if there is not any empty row (line) in your csv file. I can find them often in the end of files. Maybe you should test if your string person is (not) empty row by `string.IsNullOrEmpty(person);`

Comment: `List<string> peopleList = System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileLocation).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).ToList();`

Comment: try check your example file , maybe some line have no , char and the entries array have only 1 value and the call for the second cell comes out for a not exist value